# Type family injectivity violation despite different kinds

Tags: haskell, type-families, type-kinds

In the following example:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
newtype A a b = A (a, b)
type family F (x :: k) = (r :: k) | r -> x
type instance F (A a) = A a
type instance F (A a b) = A a b
```

In my current understanding, the first type instance deals with `*->*` kind, while the second instance deals with `*`.

So even if I'm using the same newtype `A`,  I don't see any injectivity violation risk, as absolutely no `A a` ever matches a `A a b` since they don't even have the same kind.

However GHC 8.6.5 complains that the two type instances violate injectivity but why is that? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I think this might be a limitation (bug?) of current GHC. Note that (IMO) injective type families are almost useless in GHC, since GHC won't simplify `F a ~ F b` to `a ~ b` during type checking when `F` is an injective type family (I don't know why). Injectivity seems to be used only to accept some types that would be regarded as ambiguous. At this moment, as far as I understand, I'd rather turn on `AmbiguousTypes` (which seems to be strictly more general) than `TypeFamilyDependencies`.

Comment: @chi, my understanding is that Eisenberg didn't (and probably still doesn't) have a proof that it's really safe to trust injectivity all the way.

Comment: @chi I think injectivity in the type family definition is useful for example if you have some function/typeclass  ```f :: F x -> ...``` then GHC can infer ```x``` when you use ```f```. Without injectivity ```x``` cannot be inferred and ```AllowAmbiguousTypes``` doesn't seem to help much, it seems to just move the error from the definition to the place where it's used.

Comment: @jam That's a valid point. I guess you could choose `x` at the calling point using `TypeApplications`, but having it inferred can be more convenient.